# Calculate the overlap part from pictures of two different stereos

Tags: graphics, computer-vision, stereo-3d

I have two pictures of human face. One is front face. Another is side face. Besides, I have all parameters of two cameras. How can I calculate the overlap part from the two pictures?

It's about computer vision and stereo vision.

Comment: welcome! [tour], [ask], [mre]